# Как ограничить количество оперативной памяти на программу python

Tags: python, windows, процесс

Как ограничить количество оперативной памяти на программу  python
например 1 mb

Comment: Вот что-то есть, но вроде только для линукса https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41105733/limit-ram-usage-to-python-program

Comment: Для винды вот это попробуйте https://stackoverflow.com/a/54958772/10562663.

Comment: Не знаю, но я взял вариант который помечен как правильный и он выводит     win32job.JobObjectExtended,
AttributeError: module 'win32job' has no attribute 'JobObjectExtended' я что-то делаю не правильно

Comment: можно запустить python внутри docker, а уже docker ограничить по памяти.

Comment: Не нашли ответ?

Comment: а можете мне пожалуйста написать код.Заранее спасибо.

Comment: @Stepan вопрос интересный, может и напишу, как со временем. Я думал, вы работаете над этим)